# Not able to start rails 4 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I install ruby 2.0.0 version and rails 4 on my system and it installed successfully! But, when i run command "rails server"  on cmd it is showing  following error in 'required' :

```
cannot load such file -- sqlite3-
```

Comment: Are you in the directory of a rails app when you call `rails server`?

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: How did you install rails? With the railsinstaller? Which version of sqlite3 gem did you use?